# How to save video using html5

Tags: javascript, html

I am activation the webcam using html5, I want to save whole video at my local PC. 
       How can i save video at particular path?

Comment: you cant save video with just html5.

Answer (score 1):

You can capture video using [`navigator.getUserMedia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator.getUserMedia). You can't save file to local PC by javascript API's. You can convert it to binary file using [`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob), send it to server via [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) and your server can save it to directory.

Also you can use browser file system emulation via [`window.requestFileSystem`](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/), but you will have access to this file system only from your website or app.

Also there is a good [article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/) with working example in Chrome.